# Ruby Rails - Mapping Json to Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby

I'm currently trying to sync my database up with another database with Json, but I'm running into issues with a key they're using.

```
def sync
    url = '...' # Returns "{ "class": 20, "user": "John" }"
    uri = URI(url)
    response = Net::HTTP.get(uri)
    response_hash = JSON.parse(response)
...
```

They use the keyword 'class' in their response, but I don't think I'm allowed that, so I have mine as 'cls'. Now, if I try to create a new User, I'll get an error because it cannot map 'class' to anything.

I've been trying to change the key to match my new key, but have been unable to get that to work.

Using answers such as has no effect for some reason.

```
pattern = { "class" => "cls" }

response_hash.inject({}) do |new_hash, (k, v)|
  key = pattern[k] || k
  new_hash[key] = v
  new_hash
end
```

But I did notice that I have a `Hash`, whereas some of the examples created a `HashWithIndifferentAccess`, so they could do `response_hash[:class]`, but mine would only return `nil`.

What would be the best solution for this problem? Ideally, I wouldn't have to remap any keys, and could just throw the Json into my database.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply do this

```
response_hash['cls'] = response_hash.delete('class')
```

The result would be  `{ :cls => 20, :user => "John" }` which you may directly throw into your database.

Comment: I tried what you've suggested, but it's still giving me the same results. I'm unsure why. 'cls' is not there, and 'class' still is. Oh, but I tried with creating a `HashWithIndifferentAccess` from response_hash, then calling that, and that works.

Comment: Small question, if I wanted a nested Object, how would I do that? Say the 'response' contains an Object, and I want to map that to a Model. Passing the hash fails because it expects a Model, but trying to create it early fails because it requires the parent to be created.

Comment: Try using `accepts_nested_attributes_for`. See this answer for reference : http://stackoverflow.com/a/23674227/755421

Comment: I tried adding that, but still get the same issue. `MyObject expected, got Hash`

Comment: You'll have to do a lot more than just adding that statement. Read the answer to get a complete sense of how `accepts_nested_attributes_for ` works.